# next-iron-session within express ts compile time error due to no process.env

Tags: express, dotenv

Hi I have express using TS and am following the example from the next-iron-session doc. I use dotenv to that is activated before the app is initiated so the  password can be held in the secret .env file

```
pool
.connect({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    database: 'shibari-life',
    user: 'christopherhunter-johnson',
    password: '',
    schema: 'sh',
})
.then(() => {
    console.log('DB connected');
    dotenv.config();
    app().listen('3005', () => {
        console.log('App Listening on port 3005');
    });
})
```

In the route I con figure iron-session and pass as a request param but iron-session complains that password is empty when I save the application.

```
const session = ironSession({
cookieName: 'next-iron-session/examples/express',
password: process.env.SECRET_COOKIE_PASSWORD!,
cookieOptions: {
    // the next line allows to use the session in non-https environements
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
},
```

});
router.patch(
'/api/auth/signin',
[
body('password')
.trim()
.isLength({ min: 4, max: 20 })
.withMessage('Password must betweeen 4 and 20 characters'),
],
validateRequest,
session,
async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
const { name, password } = req.body;
const errors = validationResult(req);
console.log(`/api/auth/signin called with: name: ${name} password: ${password}`);
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
next(new RequestValidationError(errors.array()));
}

```
    console.log(`secret: ${process.env.SECRET_COOKIE_PASSWORD}`);
    try {
        const user = await UserLogin.signIn({ name, password });
        console.log('user', user);
        if (!user) {
            console.log('No user create NotAuthorisedError');
            const error = new NotAuthorisedError();
            next(error);
        }
        
        req.session!.set('user', { id: user.id });
        await req.session!.save();
```

I have also attempted to pass dotenv config during the start command in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start:build": "tsc -w",
    "start:run": "nodemon -r dotenv/config build/index.js",
    "start": "concurrently npm:start:*"
},
```

The log within the body of the route shows the password is read from .env
How do I get dotenv to load password on start up?

Many thanks